# Generating R Markdown Word.docx with Plots and Updatable (Dynamic) Captions (Figure Numbers)

Tags: r, r-markdown, cpu-word, markup, caption

I'm currently using Markdown to generate a Word.docx with plots and captions using `fig.cap`

````
```{r, fig.width = 7.0, fig.height = 5.0, dpi = 400, echo=FALSE, results = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, fig.cap = "Figure 1: Plot Description", fig.align = "center"}
````

This does create a caption for the plot in the Word document, however, Word does not recognize the text as a dynamic caption. Is there a way to create dynamic captions so that the figures can be automatically renumbered when in Word and a Table of Figure can be easily created?

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic caption?

Comment: Meaning a caption that can be automatically updated in Word and also referenced to automatically create a table of figure in Word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is a bit clunky, but does result in a dynamic caption in Word. (I'm new both R and Markdown so there may be a better way to achieve the desired outcome).

```
    library(officer)
    library(officedown)
```

```
sfig_num <- run_autonum(seq_id = "Figure", pre_label = "Figure 1", bkm="1")
    
block_caption("Caption Text Here", style = "caption", autonum = sfig_num)
```